# How to access a Class value outside of it

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Sorry for such a noobish question, but, now i am writing a code that has some features i didn't know how to write by myself, so i copied them from stack overflow. I was a class i didnt study, yet i understood it mostly. The question is, how do i acess any of values created in it. Ex

```
class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.filename = filename
        self.canvrt = tk.Canvas(master, width=200, height=200, bg="#FF5733")
        self.canvrt.pack()
        self.update = self.draw().__next__
        master.after(100, self.update)

    def draw(self):
        image = Image.open(self.filename)
        angle = 0
        while True :
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
            canvas_obj = self.canvrt.create_image(
            100, 100, image=tkimage)
            self.master.after_idle(self.update)
            yield
            self.canvrt.delete(canvas_obj)
            angle += 1
            angle %= 360
```

how can i access the `canvrt` from the code? I need to acces this canvrt outisde of the class, so i can input it for example in a fucntion

Comment: Please update your question with an example of where you want to access canvrt.

Comment: ```def clean(filename):
    for widgets4 in filename.winfo_children():
        widgets4.destroy()```

Comment: ```stop = tk.Button(buttonframe2 , text=" stop", bg='grey', command = lambda : SimpleApp(rotation, 'Russian Roulete/barabannogan.jpg') and clean(#cnvrt))```

Comment: hopefully you got my idea

Comment: @AppleCidar thing is, do you want to access outside of the class if so did you create the object or do you want to access self.canvrt  from the master.winfo_children()

Comment: Please [edit] *your question* to clarify what you are trying to do. It is not clear what you are struggling with. Accessing attributes of an instance does not depend on whether its type is user defined or not, and the code as shown has *lots* of attribute accesses already.

Answer (score 2):

You create an instance of the class SinpleApp:

```
myapp = SimpleApp(master, filename)
```

And then you can access any of its variables like this:

```
myapp.canvrt
```

However, notice that it is confusing to call `filename` the argument of your function `clean` if it expects a tkinter widget...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want to access it.

```
class NewClass():

    def __init__(self,msg):
        self.msg ="Hi"
 
    def print_msg(self):
       print("Message is : ", self.msg)
```

1. Inside any of the class functions/methods, you should make use of `self`, i.e,

   ```
   self.msg
   ```
2. Outside of the class, use an *object* to access it, i.e,

   ```
   obj = NewClass("hi")
   obj.msg
   //will print Hi
   ```